# How to simplify $\frac{\sqrt{x^3}}{\sqrt[3]{x^4}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please, could someone help simplify and show the steps on how to simplify $$\frac{\sqrt{x^3}}{\sqrt[3]{x^4}}?$$
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Hint - here are some helpful rules:

$$\sqrt[n]{x}=x^{\frac{1}{n}}\tag{1}$$

$$\left(x^a\right)^b=x^{ab}\tag{2}$$

$$\frac{x^a}{x^b}=x^{a-b}\tag{3}$$

Applying $(1)$ and $(2)$ to the numerator and denominator gets you to a form where you can apply $(3)$. You should end up with something of the form $x^c$.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite as $$\large{\frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{x^{\frac{4}{3}}}}$$

Then $$\frac{3}{2} -\frac{4}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$$

So the solution is $\large{x^{\frac{1}{6}}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\large{\sqrt{x^3} = (x^3)^{\frac{1}{2}} = x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
Now 
$$\large{\sqrt[3]{x^4} = (x^4)^{\frac{1}{3}} = x^{\frac{4}{3}}}$$

Now you divide these two $$\large{\frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{x^{\frac{4}{3}}} = x^{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{4}{3}} = \color{red}{x^{\frac{1}{6}} =\sqrt[6]{x}}}$$